# Como deixar o loop separado no row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa noite, basicamentemente eu preciso pegar um .json e fazer um loop nele para pegar todas a tabelas com o nome titulo, mas ao fazer isso ele me retorna tudo junto e não consigo separa certinho para colocar  dentro de uma table.

```
$("#button").click(function() 
{
    var url = "http://localhost/log.json";

    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data)
    {
        var title = "";
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) 
        {
            title += data[i].title ;
            $("#nome").text(title);     
        }
    });
});

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td id="nome"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Bem se não fico claro, eu quero que cada nome fique dentro de uma  (table)
>   e não tudo junto como esta agora!, Os títulos foram retirandos por
>   scraper que fiz no xvideos

**Obrigado se alguem puder ajudar!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis um exemplo perfeito para o seu caso. Está na documentação do `jQuery`.

`JavaScript`:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

E um `JSON` super simples, só para a exemplificação do código:

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Eis o link para aprofundar seus estudos: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/